# Get MAX and MIN in a row SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT CandidateID, t_Candidate.Name, ISNULL(CAST(AVG(Rate) AS DECIMAL(12,2)),0) AS Rate, t_Ambassadors.Name AS CN
        FROM t_Vote INNER JOIN t_Candidate 
        ON t_Vote.CandidateID = t_Candidate.ID
        INNER JOIN t_Ambassadors 
        ON t_Vote.AmbassadorID = t_Ambassadors.ID
        GROUP BY Rate, CandidateID, t_Candidate.Name, t_Ambassadors.Name
    )MySrc
    PIVOT
    (
        AVG(Rate)
        FOR CN IN ([Jean],[Anna],[Felicia])
    )AS nSrc

)SELECT CandidateID, Name, CAST([Jean] AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS AHH ,CAST([Anna] AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS MK,CAST([Felicia] AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS DIL, CAST(([Jean] + [Anna] + [Felicia])/3 AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS Total
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Cte.CandidateID, cte.Name, cte.[Jean], cte.[Anna], cte.[Felicia]
```

I have solved my previous problem with the above query. I created a new question because I have new problem.  How do I get the MAX and MIN rate in a row?

The following is the result I get from the above query:

```
| CandidateID | Name |  AHH  |  MK  | DIL  | Total |
|-------------|------|-------|------|------|-------|
|     CID1    | Jay  | 7.00  | 3.00 | 3.00 | 4.33  |
|     CID2    | Mia  | 2.00  | 9.00 | 7.00 | 6.00  |
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
| CandidateID | Name |  AHH  |  MK  | DIL  | Total |
|-------------|------|-------|------|------|-------|
|     CID1    | Jay  | 7.00  | 3.00 | 3.00 | 3.00  |
|     CID2    | Mia  | 2.00  | 9.00 | 7.00 | 7.00  |
```

So what happened on the 2nd result is that, it removed the Highest and Lowest score/rate from the row and Get the average of remaining rate/score.  AHH, MK and DIL are not the only Voters, there are 14 of them, I just took the 3 first to make it short and clearer.

Comment: You mean you'll end up with something like `CAST(([Jean] + [Anna] + [Felicia] + [name4] + ... [name14] - MIN(felicia,name4...name14) - MAX(felicia,name4...name14)) / 14  AS DECIMAL(12,2))`? Doesn't look right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking by something like the following (though I'm using case aggregation rather than a pivot).

Essentially, it does the same thing your query does except that it uses a row number to figure out the highest and lowest and exclude them from the final "total" (in the case of a tie, it'll just select one of them, but you can use `RANK()` instead of row_number() if you don't want to include tied highest/lowest in the average):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT CandidateID,
           Name,
           CN,
           Rate,
           Lowest = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CandidateID, Name ORDER BY Rate),
           Highest = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CandidateID, Name ORDER BY Rate DESC)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CandidateID,
               t_Candidate.Name,
               CN = t_Ambassadors.Name,
               Rate = ISNULL(CAST(AVG(Rate) AS DECIMAL(12,2)),0)
        FROM t_Vote
        JOIN t_Candidate
            ON t_Vote.CandidateID = t_Candidate.ID
        JOIN t_Ambassadors
            ON t_Vote.AmbassadorID = t_Ambassadors.ID
        GROUP BY CandidateID, t_Candidate.Name, t_Ambassadors.Name
    ) AS T
)
SELECT CandidateID,
       Name,
       AHH = MAX(CASE WHEN CN = 'Jean' THEN Rate END),
       MK = MAX(CASE WHEN CN = 'Anna' THEN Rate END),
       DIL = MAX(CASE WHEN CN = 'Felicia' THEN Rate END), -- and so on and so forth for each CN
       Total = AVG(CASE WHEN Lowest != 1 AND Highest != 1 THEN Rate END)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY CandidateID, Name;
```

**EDIT:** It is possible to do this using PIVOT, but unless I'm mistaken, it becomes a matter of working out the average of the ones that aren't highest and lowest before pivoting, which becomes a bit more convoluted. It's all around easier to use case aggregation, IMO.

Comment: yeah your logic is correct, that was my first way of doing things but having problem when doing the group by, anyway.. i'll try this one out i'll mark as answer when correct